# How to make Tomcat 6 server JSON content

Tags: tomcat, servlets, tomcat6, jackrabbit

When I try to request for a non existent resource using a GET request for -

http://localhost:8080/jackrabbit/server/default/jcr:root/user/abc/article/article-1.0.json

I am expecting a 404 response but in JSON format. But instead I get an html response -

```
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/6.0.32 - Error report</title>...</body></html>
```

How can I make sure that this content is returned in JSON format instead of HTML format. I have specified the following in web.xml but that did not help -

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>json</extension>
    <mime-type>application/json</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should configure a 404 error page that sets the proper content type and outputs JSON.

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/notFoundJSON</location>
</error-page>
```

Where `/notFoundJSON` is mapped to a servlet that uses `response.setContentType(..)` and writes JSON to the `response.getWriter()`

Comment: Can you please let me know how to do that or point me to some link? Thanks, gg